# System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest Ldap Query Execution Issue

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am using DirectorySearcher class to query the active directory. It gives all the records in a single page (more than 5000). I want to get 100 records per page. So I moved to SearchRequest class. Using SearchRequest class I can get 100 records per page. But for particular query it is not working. I want to get all the users with their "samaccountname or displayname starts with 'a'" works fine. Then I want to get all the users with their "samaccountname and displayname starts with 'a'", this it is not working. I can guess the reason, some of the users starts their samaccountname with a not having any displayname. Any workaround for this issue? Please guide me

Please refer the following code

```
        //This query works fine
        //string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(|(samaccountname=a*)(displayname=a*)))";


        /* Not works */
        string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(&(samaccountname=a*)(displayname=a*)))";
        LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(serverName);
        string[] attribs = { "samaccountname", "displayname" };

        // create a SearchRequest object
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
                                                (scope,
                                                 filter,
                                                 System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree,
                                                 attribs);

        SortRequestControl sortRequest = new SortRequestControl("samaccountname", false);
        searchRequest.Controls.Add(sortRequest);

        VlvRequestControl vlvRequest =
            new VlvRequestControl(0, numEntries, offsetVal);
        searchRequest.Controls.Add(vlvRequest);

        SearchResponse searchResponse =
            (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searchRequest);

        if (searchResponse.Controls.Length != 2 ||
            !(searchResponse.Controls[0] is SortResponseControl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The server does not support VLV");
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What's the error? The filter is valid so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want displayName in Active Directory?  Perhaps fullName or CN would be a more accurate choice.

Comment: No, I may need to query givenname or sn. I know that, a user will must have have cn or fullname attribute. The problem is querying with the needed attribute. The attribute may be displayname, pwdlastset, lastlogon, etc..